# Should I use Html.Label helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

In an MVC project I use an HTML.Label helper as follows:-

```
@Html.Label("FirstName", "First Name", New With {.class = "FieldLabel"})
```

Which outputs

```
<label class="FieldLabel" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
```

I've also got a corresponding input for this label.

This might sound like a stupid question, but if I was just to enter the direct output into my view instead of using the HTML helper is there absolutely any difference?  So are there any advantages/disadvantages to using an HTML helper for a label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference.

For simple stuff like labels, I don't really see the benefit of using html helpers. The helper code is longer than the actual html.

However, html helpers are great for model binding.

So if i want to bind a label or other form elements to my ViewModel i use

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

This ensures that model binding works correctly. The form elements are outputted with the necessary attributes so that when the form is posted to the server, the model parameter is populated automatically on the server side.

It also takes sure of making sure that your labels are linked to the correct form elements.
The @Html.LabelFor helper will output the following html

```
<label for="Username">Username</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

HtmlHelpers are designed to generate **dynamic content**; So, if you have such a scenario for your project those are necessary.

In your code

```
@Html.Label("FirstName", "First Name", New With {.class = "FieldLabel"})
```

everything is static, so there is no obligation to use HTMlHelper.

Answer (score 0):

Html.Label gives you a label for an input whose name matches the specified input text